# javascript - missing ) after for-loop control

Tags: javascript

Im trying to solve problem #4 on project Euler,im using a simple for-loop to sift through each element of the array and `"missing ) after for-loop control"`

Code below

```
var palidrome = function (num) {
        var numstr = (num).toString().split("");
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0, i2 = numstr.length - 1; i < numstr.length / 2 && i2 >= numstr.length / 2; i++, i2--) {

            if (numstr[i] !== numstr[i2]) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                if (count == 3) {
                    return numstr.join("");
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
      };
    for (var i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
        for (var j = 100; j = < i; j++) {
            if (palidrome(i * j) !== 0) {
                alert(palidrome(i * j));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for the assistance,much appreciated.

Comment: Try to reduce this code removing one statement after another until you get it worked. Than you'll know the exact place of the error. When you develop follow the opposite - make small steps and check it works after every one.

Comment: where do you run the code above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for loop you have error: `j = < i` must be `j <= i`

```
for (var i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
    for (var j = 100; j <= i; j++) {
        if (palidrome(i * j) !== 0) {
            alert(palidrome(i * j));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```